# Best plan for developing in Office 365

Tags: office-365

From what I have read here [How to: Create a Developer Site within your existing Office 365 subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692554%28v=office.15%29.aspx) the plan "Office 365 Midsize Business" should be the smallest one to get a developer site.

But from what I see at [Compare Office 365 for business plans](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/office-365-fur-unternehmen-plane-vergleichen-FX102918419.aspx%20%22%22) is that this plan does not exist anymore.

So my question is what would be the smallest plan to get a developer site except using a Office 365 developer subscription?

Answer (score 1):

If you check [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/compare-all-office-365-for-business-plans-FX104051403.aspx) the plan you are talking about is exist(which is12.50/ user/month).

Another option is if you are a MSDN subscriber? Visual Studio Ultimate and Visual Studio Premium with MSDN subscribers receive an Office 365 Developer Subscription as a benefit.

Comment: Interesting fact when changing this link to Germany this plan simply disappears and only two categories of plans remain. https://office.microsoft.com/de-de/business/compare-all-office-365-for-business-plans-FX104051403.aspx And I do have an MSDN subscription but it is one from MPN which does not include an Office 365 Developer Subscription.

Comment: then may be it is not available for Germany.

Comment: I don't think so because in the German version of "How to: Create a Developer Site within your existing Office 365 subscription" this plan is also mentioned. Very confusing.

Comment: Looked at your link again today and now "Office 365 Midsize Business" is also missing in the English version. Maybe due to the announcement of new plans by Microsoft [New Office 365 plans for small and mid-sized businesses available today](http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/02/new-office-365-plans-small-mid-sized-businesses-available-today/)

Comment: yup you are right, looks like they change it today.